# @JsonDeserialize converter use StdDelegatingDeserializer by default

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to use
@JsonDeserialize annotation with converter

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = PGJsonConverter.class)
```

I'm using spring data rest project and when sending PUT request there is calling deserialize method from super class JsonDeserializer of StdDelegatingDeserializer

```
 public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, T intoValue)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Can not update object of type "
                +intoValue.getClass().getName()+" (by deserializer of type "+getClass().getName()+")");
    }
```

I'f i don't use @JsonDeserialize we have BeanDeserializer instead of StdDelegatingDeserializer.

In DeserializeCache:356 I found the condition

```
 Converter<Object,Object> conv = beanDesc.findDeserializationConverter();
        if (conv == null) { // nope, just construct in normal way
            return (JsonDeserializer<Object>) _createDeserializer2(ctxt, factory, type, beanDesc);
        }
```

My goal is to use BeanDeserializer with custom converter. How to implement this?